# handle gps shifting on google map javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a playback solution to animate and move vehicle marker on the map based on the stored way points sent via gps device.

Gps device send some shifted way points **to the opposite direction** which affect the drawn route on the map
(the calculated route is wrong) and below the code i use to do that:

```
function setRoutes() {

var directionsDisplay = new Array();

var rendererOptions = {
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    preserveViewport: true
}
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;



var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: wayPoints,
    travelMode: travelMode
};

directionsService.route(request,
    function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation = new Object();
            endLocation = new Object();

            // For each route, display summary information.
            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;

            disp = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
            disp.setMap(null);
            disp.setDirections(response);


            //Markers               
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                    startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                    // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
                    //marker[routeNum] = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, msg.DeviceId, legs[i].start_address, "green");
                }
                endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
                endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;

                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                    for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                        polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
       startAnimation();
    });
    }
```

what should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps waypoints limit - show long routes accurately from raw GPS data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360786/google-maps-waypoints-limit-show-long-routes-accurately-from-raw-gps-data)

Comment: Related question [draw a path from GEO locations from GPS snapped to road](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318816/draw-a-path-from-geo-locations-from-gps-snapped-to-road)

Comment: Have you tried snap to road: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#demo?